# my mongoose query not returning only distinct data from database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

As i wanted get only the data of them whose having only different username and the data need to created last as i have tried certain code, and i have shared the snippets of that codes kindly help me to the
expected output :)

previous code

```
formRouter
  .route("/")
  .get((req, res, next) => {
    Profiles.find(req.query)
      .then(
        (profile) => {
          res.statusCode = 200;
          res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
          res.json(profile);
        },
        (err) => next(err)
      )
      .catch((err) => next(err));
  })
```

previous code returns

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5ef4fcaee0a4809078b93d6e",
        "username": "ram",
        "user_tag": "AcDc",
        "old_rank_name": "Recruit"
        "createdAt": "2020-06-25T19:36:14.293Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-06-25T19:36:14.293Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ef747561ad9eb878c176dce",
        "username": "shyam",
        "user_tag": "null",
        "old_rank_name": "Recruit"
        "createdAt": "2020-06-27T13:19:18.009Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-06-27T13:19:18.009Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ef747a31ad9eb878c176dcf",
        "username": "dhyam",
        "user_tag": "null",
        "old_rank_name": "Recruit"
        "createdAt": "2020-06-27T13:20:35.704Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-06-27T13:20:35.704Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ef747ae1ad9eb878c176dd0",
        "username": "dhyam",
        "user_tag": "null",
        "old_rank_name": "Legal Officer"
        "createdAt": "2020-06-27T13:20:46.168Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-06-27T13:20:46.168Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ef747bf1ad9eb878c176dd1",
        "username": "dhyam",
        "user_tag": "null",
        "old_rank_name": "Legal Specialist"
        "createdAt": "2020-06-27T13:21:03.972Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-06-27T13:21:03.972Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

expected output will be like distinct username with last created data

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5ef4fcaee0a4809078b93d6e",
        "username": "ram",
        "user_tag": "AcDc",
        "old_rank_name": "Recruit"
        "createdAt": "2020-06-25T19:36:14.293Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-06-25T19:36:14.293Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ef747561ad9eb878c176dce",
        "username": "shyam",
        "user_tag": "null",
        "old_rank_name": "Recruit"
        "createdAt": "2020-06-27T13:19:18.009Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-06-27T13:19:18.009Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ef747bf1ad9eb878c176dd1",
        "username": "dhyam",
        "user_tag": "null",
        "old_rank_name": "Legal Specialist"
        "createdAt": "2020-06-27T13:21:03.972Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-06-27T13:21:03.972Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

code what i tried

```
global.arr = [];

.get((req, res, next) => {
    Profiles.find().distinct("username")
      .then(
        (profile) => {
          var i;
          for(i=0; i<profile.length; i++)
          {
          Profiles.findOne({ username: profile[i] })
          .sort({ _id: -1 })
          .then(
            (user) => {
              arr.push(user) //from here i tried get array which is global but not working as console.log(arr) works fine
            },
            (err) => next(err)
          )
          .catch((err) => next(err));
        }
          res.json(arr); //as i am not getting updated array here
        },
        (err) => next(err)
      )
      .catch((err) => next(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

and i come with this solution after alot hit and try

```
formRouter
  .route("/")
  .get((req, res, next) => {
    Profiles.find().distinct("username")
      .then(
        (profile) => {
          var i;
          var arr = [];
          for(i=0; i<profile.length; i++)
          {
            var x = i
          Profiles.findOne({ username: profile[i] })
          .sort({ _id: -1 })
          .then(
            (user) => {
              arr.push(user) 

              //added part
              if(arr.length==profile.length)
              {
                res.json(arr);
              }

            },
            (err) => next(err)
          )
          .catch((err) => next(err));
        } 
        },
        (err) => next(err)
      )
      .catch((err) => next(err));
  })
```

Comment: can anybody help to find out more optimized solution which does take less time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$group` with `$last` for distinct `username` with latest `create date`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$username",
      "doc": {
        "$last": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$doc"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RhAkauZgnw4)